# How do Python distributable modules work with external libs

Tags: python, numpy, makefile, import

I apologise in advance, as I am rather new to Python programming, but I was curious as to how this system works. My question is: if I write a Python script and make it distributable, but my program imports other external libraries such as numpy or scipy (which is what I am working on currently) how does it all work together? It is my understanding that the user would still have to install the libraries separately or I need to write a separate makefile that runs a script to install it while my distributable is being installed. Am  I right in this opinion? Advice would be greatly appreciated. Also a explanation how it works internally given your answer. Thanks a lot! Appreciate your time!

Comment: Very popular in python circles are virtualenv and its cousin virtuenvwrapper.  Using those, you can use pip to install 3rd party packages.  Then Create a requirements.txt file using pip, which you distribute with your application.  It is easy for the receiver to download all requirements

Comment: I shall try all the options and get back here.thanks @pjs

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to ensure that dependent modules are installed is through *pip -r*.

Essentially, make a *requirements.txt* along with your script for users to install the correct modules and versions.

Inside the text file should look like this:

```
Flask==0.11.1
```

You can use:

```
pip freeze
```

To find which modules you have installed

EDIT: This is implied your script is small and not packaged inside a .dmg or .exe file.

Comment: What if I want it to be executable? what would be my options then? My goal here is for the end user to be able to install my module and run whenever possible.Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: If it's for the Window platform then take a look at: [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

`numpy`, `scipy` takes a long time to install in a virtualenv.  For this reason I would not recommend virtualenv like others have.  You could try `pyinstaller` to create an OS specific executable.  Haven't tried it with numpy or scipy myself though.

http://www.pyinstaller.org